# add image along the lineString in Openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I would like to  place images on a line. For example, instead of a dotted or dashed line, I could include a symbol of a ship or a character (e.g. |) repeated along the line.
Here is code:

```
lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    opacity: 1,
    size:20,
    src: './icon.png'
  })),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'black',
    width: 5,
    lineDash: [10]
  })
});
```

I want to get a result like this:

[image: result]

Here is my example, but it cannot show the image along with line. http://jsfiddle.net/Wenhua1224/jguxq4j0/

Comment: Hi @WenhuaHu, this a duplicate question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105107/images-along-on-a-line

Comment: @ Jonatas Walker, Yes, but that guy said this way works, but i didnt solve it out with the way he provides  [  `lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                     opacity: 1,
                     size:20,
                     src: './icon.png'
                     })),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'black',
      width: 5,
lineDash: [10]
     })
     });`] That is why I asked.

Comment: Oh I see, it looks like that's not possible yet.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker ok, thanks

Comment: It is possible.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306976/add-image-along-the-linestring/306979